# How to get content to float to the bottom of its container?

Tags: html, css

The picture shows what I need to achieve with css. What changes I have to make in css to get a desired result? Is there a way to move it to the bottom without using margin-top? 
There's also should be the next and previous arrows at the middle of the image.

See the code below.

Thank You.

[image: desired result]

```css
.gallery {

 width: 940px;
 margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
}

.img-1 {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 400px;
 background: #a7a7a7;
}
.img-2 {
 float: left;
 width:300px;
 height: 400px;
 background: #a7a7a7;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.img-3{
 float: right;
 width:300px;
 height: 400px;
 background: #a7a7a7;
}

.h2_img {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 28px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
}

.p_img {
 color: #ccc;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.span_img {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 11px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
 font-size: 11px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
 -moz-border-radius: 28px;
 border-radius: 28px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin: 20px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="img-1">
   <span class="span_img">IMG 1</span>
   <h2 class="h2_img">Some text, some great text</h2>
   <p class="p_img">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-2">
   <span class="span_img">IMG 2</span>
   <h2 class="h2_img">Some text, some great text</h2>
   <p class="p_img">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-3">
   <span class="span_img">IMG 3</span>
   <h2 class="h2_img">Some text, some great text</h2>
   <p class="p_img">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to wrap the content in a separate element and position it.

```css
.img-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #a7a7a7;
  position: relative;
}
.img-1 div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-1"> <span class="span_img">IMG 1</span>

  <div>
    <h2 class="h2_img">Some text, some great text</h2>

    <p class="p_img">Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```